# When changing gltf model texture show only a colored surface

Tags: javascript, three.js

I trying to change the texture of the GLTF model dynamically when clicked in a carousel of images and this images are stored in base64 strings.
But when I change the texture it shows only a colored surface.

[model before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8dny.png) => [image to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kOU0.png) => [model after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Qqg.png)

```js
    let texture = loader.load(base64String);
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set(30, 30);
    texture.anisotropy = 16;
    texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    texture.flipY = false;

    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: texture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    gltf_model.traverse ( ( o ) => {
        if ( o.isMesh ) {
            o.material = material;
        }
    });
```